# Saving output of an URL as Image on local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to execute an URL in javaScript, that URL generates an chart and then save that chart in my local machine as JPEG or PNG. For example once I clock on a button a particular URL gets called. output of that URL is an graph image. without showing that image on screen I have to save that in my local machine.

Please let me know how I can complete this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What have you already tried? We are here to help, not do the work for you.

Comment: What charts are you using? Highcharts have "save" functionality. Else try looking something for js screenshot. I have done that by using highcharts and saving chart as PDF.